# Recommended approach to sync Google Cloud Storage buckets cross continents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Looks like there is no built-in mechanism to sync (one-way) two GCS buckets cross continents (e.g. US -> EU). There could be many ways to do it manually. Does anyone have any real world experience for recommended approaches? For my use case, the latency is not a concern.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data transfer service to replicate from a bucket to another one. It's asynchronous and you can overwrite the existing files: for 1 way replication, it's great

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service